# Exclude merged branch from git log

Tags: git

Is it possible to omit merged branches from the history to get a more clear view?

### Motivation

For the sake of Gerrit reviews and clean history, I am meant to squash commits into the master branch.

In order to locally keep my full history, I pull back from master after squashing. Essentially

```
git checkout master
git merge --squash ticket-branch
# ... wait until code review has passed
git pull origin master
git checkout ticket-branch
git merge --no-ff master
```

In practice, I push for code review and merge back from `origin/master` after it has been accepted, but that shouldn't affect the question.

This may result in a hard-to-read history like this:

```
>>> git log --graph --all --oneline                    >>> git log --graph --all --oneline --author-date-order

* 7bef64f (master) Commit 19                           * 7bef64f (master) Commit 19
* 7e42958 Commit 18                                    | *   11a808c (HEAD -> ticket-branch) Merge branch...
* ff9df00 Commit 17                                    | |\
* 835b71d Commit 16: More changes on master            * | | 7e42958 Commit 18
| *   11a808c (HEAD -> ticket-branch) Merge branch...  | * | 83e1780 Commit 14
| |\                                                   * | | ff9df00 Commit 17
| |/                                                   | * | a02d52c Commit 11
|/|                                                    * | | 835b71d Commit 16: More changes on master
* | ca35688 Commit 15                                  | |/
* | f3bc917 Commit 13                                  |/|
* | 4025a7e Commit 12                                  | * 3dda274 Commit 10
* | f29e4b8 Commit  9                                  * | ca35688 Commit 15
* | b8ac49d Commit  5                                  | * 381ba96 Commit  8
| * 83e1780 Commit 14                                  * | f3bc917 Commit 13
| * a02d52c Commit 11                                  | * b5c11cd Commit  7
| * 3dda274 Commit 10                                  * | 4025a7e Commit 12
| * 381ba96 Commit  8                                  * | f29e4b8 Commit  9
| * b5c11cd Commit  7                                  | * ad976de Commit  6
| * ad976de Commit  6                                  * | b8ac49d Commit  5
| * fc02828 Commit  4                                  | * fc02828 Commit  4
|/                                                     |/
* 70e48a8 Commit  3                                    * 70e48a8 Commit  3
* 8cc2643 Commit  2                                    * 8cc2643 Commit  2
* 45385ec Commit  1: Faking a master history.          * 45385ec Commit  1: Faking a master history.
* f7f20a7 initial commit                               * f7f20a7 initial commit
```

### Working Example

I used the following sequence of commands to create the mockup:

```
rm -rf '/tmp/squash-history-demo'
mkdir -p '/tmp/squash-history-demo'
cd '/tmp/squash-history-demo'
git init
touch a b; git add a b; git commit -m 'initial commit'
git checkout master
echo  1 > a;   git commit --all -m 'Commit  1: Faking a master history.'
git checkout master
echo  2 > a;   git commit --all -m 'Commit  2'
git checkout master
echo  3 > a;   git commit --all -m 'Commit  3'

: work proceeds on ticket branch an master in parallel
git checkout -b ticket-branch
git checkout ticket-branch
echo  4 > b;   git commit --all -m 'Commit  4'
git checkout master
echo  5 > a;   git commit --all -m 'Commit  5'
git checkout ticket-branch
echo  6 > b;   git commit --all -m 'Commit  6'
git checkout ticket-branch
echo  7 > b;   git commit --all -m 'Commit  7'
git checkout ticket-branch
echo  8 > b;   git commit --all -m 'Commit  8'
git checkout master
echo  9 > a;   git commit --all -m 'Commit  9'
git checkout ticket-branch
echo 10 > b;   git commit --all -m 'Commit 10'
git checkout ticket-branch
echo 11 > b;   git commit --all -m 'Commit 11'
git checkout master
echo 12 > a;   git commit --all -m 'Commit 12'
git checkout master
echo 13 > a;   git commit --all -m 'Commit 13'
git checkout ticket-branch
echo 14 > b;   git commit --all -m 'Commit 14'
git checkout master
echo 15 > a;   git commit --all -m 'Commit 15'

: -- Squash merge
git merge --squash ticket-branch
git checkout ticket-branch
git merge --no-ff master

git checkout master
git checkout master
echo 16 > a;   git commit --all -m 'Commit 16: More changes on master'
git checkout master
echo 17 > a;   git commit --all -m 'Commit 17'
git checkout master
echo 18 > a;   git commit --all -m 'Commit 18'
git checkout master
echo 19 > a;   git commit --all -m 'Commit 19'

git checkout ticket-branch
git log --oneline --graph --all --decorate=short
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the remote repository and your local repository will be out of sync if you squash in the remote when completing a PR. Your local branches will appear to never become merged into master.

Comment: The function of `git log` is to walk the commit graph, and as it does the walk, print something about each of (or some selected subset of) the commits walked. You have options that modify the walk, such as `--first-parent`, and options that modify which commits walked are printed, such as those in the History Simplification section. If one of those (or a combination of those) does what you'd like, that's what to use. But there may not be anything built in that does what you want.

Comment: In this case, the main stumbling block will (I believe) be that the commit produced via `git merge --squash` isn't a merge and therefore has no linkage to your original commit sequence, so there is nothing *in* the graph that can coordinate these.

Comment: @torek The merge doesn't cause any particular issues, since I merge back to `ticket-branch`. Since I know that at that time the master contains the things I want in `ticket-branch`, I can just `git merge -X theirs master`; That also ensures that the next time around I can make another squash merge.

Comment: Ah. (Beware of `-X theirs`'s auto-resolutions; depending on your situation, it might mis-resolve some conflicts. What you really want is `-s theirs`, which does not exist, but can be synthesized. But that's a separate issue.) In that case, you have a merge commit that will identify what to prune during the commit graph walk, but it's not one that `git log` itself can use for pruning. So `git log` won't be able to do this. If you write your own revision-walking program—basically, your own `git log`—that understands how you use the graph, you can achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

1. `ticket-branch` is not merged into `master`. `master` has been merged into that `ticket-branch`.
2. yes you can **not** show all branches when using `git log`. You are using the `--all` flag which shows all branches. If you don't use that flag, you will only see the history of your current branch.

Comment: I will see all ancestors, including the ones merged from `master` into `ticket-branch`. That's what I'm trying to avoid. I've tried to clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

So.... you want to keep all history but you also want to squash it for the PR that will be merged to master? It's achievable with a merge, I think.... so, say, branch featureX (created from master) has 4 commits **in a straight line, no merges**

So.... now is squashing time for the PR. Let's leave the branch where it it.

```
git checkout -b prX #branch for pr X
# this is one way I squash
git reset --soft HEAD~4 # set branch pointer 4 revisions back... all changes for featureX are in index
git commit -m "Feature X"
# push this branch so that the PR is created
# then, when the branch is merged to master:
git checkout featureX # original development branch for the feature
git merge -m "merging changes from master" master
```

Now you have kept the squashed version and the original development work in your private branch

Comment: I'm already doing almost exactly this; That's what results in the hard-to-read development tree and is the reason I want to omit part of the history from the log. I've tried to clarify the question.